# Is it possible to write a TFS Shared Query with a parameter on a custom field?

Tags: tfs, workitem

I have a set of queries on the Team home page that use the standard @Me, for example to let different users quickly get to bugs they have personally raised, PBIs they created that are now in a certain state.

The users are in customer groups and I'd like to have a similar set of queries showing as tiles on the home page, e.g. "Team Open Bugs", "Team PBIs for review".

Is it possible to write a query that does this -

Select all [work item type] from [team project] where [state] and [@myCustomerTeam] ?

From what I have read so far I believe this is not possible, and certainly not possible through the UI. I'm curious to find out if anyone has solved a problem like this - having different customer groups see different Team Favorites tiles on the Home page of Team Web Access - in some other way. I'm going to try making three sets of queries and putting different permissions on them (there are TFS groups that correspond to the Customer Group field) but I'm not confident that Denying even Read permission on the query itself will stop the tile showing on everyone's homepage.

Edited to say that solution worked for my purposes, as per comment.

Still interested to know if anyone has managed something like this more cleanly. In this case the field I would have liked to parameterise happened to be something I could map to a completely different type of thing, thus shifting the problem. I can imagine wanting to parameterise a field that didn't have that characteristic though.

Comment: Setting permissions for the different user groups worked; the queries that are not relevant to a particular group do not show for users in that group. The Home page tiles don't show either (which is great, that was the most important outcome)